# minimazing parallax error by picking points

Tags: c++, algorithm, points

I have 2 images of the same scene but with slightly difference. It is due to the fact that I have taken the picture with 2 different equipment, and one is not perfectly right. 
That create a little parallax problem somewhere on the photo. It is really slight when you compare the 2 photos, but just enough disturbing for what I want to do with those images.

My question is : what would be the best algorithm to minimize the created error?

What I was thinking was :
pick X points in the first image, pick their correspondance points in the other image, then create a function that project the first points to the other and then apply this function to all the points in the scene.
Something like that :
[image]
(Red point are picked points, and other colors are the deformation of each points in the scene (probably not correct since I did it fastly).

Would it be a good way to proceed? If yes, what would be a good interpolation algorithm using the points.

If no, is there any other algorithm that I could use in order the minimize the error?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using 4 pairs of points you can calculate matrix of perspective transformation and later apply this transformation to the whole image.

OpenCV library contains `getPerspectiveTransform` function for this case (also `findHomography`). You can also apply `warpPerspective` to correct image.

[Example](https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/)

Comment: I already tried several opencv algorthm (estimate2Daffine, perspective, homography) and since every result were wrong, I am wondering if the parallax error can be corrected via this kind of algo.
For me, I think not, because those algorithm assume that all modification are global on the image while in my case it is possible that it is not a global modification (I think). For example, with parallax, the error increase as the object is far from the objectives :/

Comment: Such (perspective) transformation makes correction only for one plane. Two photos from different points allow to evaluate depth for scene objects with specific points, but I doubt that correction for all distances could be performed with quality